# PoC Hadoop: assess hardware requirements

Tags: hadoop, nodes, hardware

I am trying to find out the minimum requirements I need to develop a proof of concept with Hadoop. Can you help me assess if this is appropriate?

Basically, this will be my architecture

[image]

Thank you very much for your help!